# Aspectj not working after transition java 8 to java 11 ee project

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, java-11, java-ee-8

I have Java EE (javaee-api version: 8) project running and after migrating to java 11 aspect does not seem to work.

Compiled .class with an annotation that we use for aspects is not modified by the plugin also as it was before on java 8...

My dependencies at the moment are.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>11</complianceLevel>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Also tried to use this plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.nickwongdev</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.6</version>
```

my aspect looks like this.

```
public aspect Aspect {


    Object around(): execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(annotation) {

    }

}
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

I have also updated **maven-compiler-plugin** to version **3.10.1** which seems to be caused the issue.

But after downgrading it to **2.5.1** - everything is working fine

Comment: I very much doubt that Maven Compiler Plugin as such is the root cause of your problem. I suspect that you simply did not configure it correctly. You not sharing your full POM or - even better - a full, minimal sample project reproducing the problem, makes both your statement and my educated guess mere speculation. Like this, the answer does not help anyone. Please, make your problem reproducible in order to help the whole community you asked for help here learn something from your situation or suggest a better solution.